# Jquery selectable not in list

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working on a project that pulls a series of items form an SQL database and puts them into a grid of divs. The user then selects a series of divs the content of which will be placed into a different SQL database (basically separating 1 database into 4). I am trying to use the JQueryUI function selectable to achieve my selection method but it does not seem to be doing anything. From my research I can only seem to find examples of people using selectable in lists. Is it possible for me to use it with divs/spans or do i have to use lists inorder to get selectable to work correctly?

Code Examples:

```
htmlResponse &= "<div id=""selectable"">"
        While sqlReader.Read = True
            htmlResponse &= "<div class=""row"">"
            htmlResponse &= "<span class=""rowText cell"">" + sqlReader("RowText").ToString() + "</span>"
            htmlResponse &= "<span class=""rowtoCol cell"">" + "</span>"
            htmlResponse &= "</div>"
        End While
        htmlResponse &= "</div>"


getData(currentRows, sortColumn, columnDir);
$("#selectable").selectable();
```

first is my VB code that makes my grid and the second is my javascript to show I am making the grid before attempting to make them selectable.

Comment: Share some code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a 'selectable' class to your spans, and use filter option of selectable plugin, like this:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({ filter: "span.selectable" });
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FHtuP/